# Change how long power button must be held down Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, timeout

I had a ThinkPad w/ Ubuntu 20.04, and you just had to touch the power button and the dialouge for the dialouge box "Power Off" with the options Cancel / Restart / Power Off would pop up.

I got an Acer Aspire and now I have to hold down the power button > 1 second for that same dialouge to pop up...

How do I change my new computer to instantly show the dialogue when the power button is pressed?

Comment: You don't because it doesn't depend on the OS or software.

Comment: Look in the BIOS settings. Maybe.